# Is there a way to use a ternary operator to render an option similar to the below?

Tags: reactjs, ternary-operator

I'm mapping over a list of tasks and displaying a card for each. Inside each card, I'm populating a select box by .map of an array of employees. This select box is being used to assign a userId to the task object, which is in another table. I wonder if there is a way to add an option to the select box that shows the task currently is unassigned (task object's userId = ""). I've written the ternary operator below, but it does not yield the result I seek.

Thank you for your assistance!

**An update, currently I am trying...**

```
<label htmlFor="assignTo" className="assignToLabel">Assign To</label>
                                <select className="form-control"
                                    onChange={this.assignTo}
                                    id="assignTo" >

                                    {this.props.employees.map(employee => {
                                        if (this.props.task.userId == "") {
                                            return <option key="0" id="0" defaultValue="0" selected>
                                                Assign To:
                                            </option>
                                        } else if (employee.id === this.props.task.userId) {
                                            return <option key={employee.id} id={employee.id} defaultValue={employee.id} selected>
                                                {employee.name} {employee.surname}
                                            </option>
                                        } else {
                                            return <option key={employee.id} id={employee.id} value={employee.id} >
                                                {employee.name} {employee.surname}
                                            </option>
                                        }
                                    })}
                                </select>
```

This also is not working, the "Assign To" option is not returned. Anyone else have thoughts on this?

**Continuing gratitude!**

Comment: what do you get when userId of task is 0

Comment: Same; I get nothing. I'm wondering if I need to return the option, though Visual Studio does not like how I'm trying to insert the return into the ternary.

Comment: Just to be sure,"this.props.task.userId" is really a string, not a number?

Comment: problem can be  `this.props.task.userId === '0'`. May be it's not a string so can you change it to `this.props.task.userId ==  '0'` and check

Comment: Bravo @JS Engine, but a better way to do this is to keep the "===" and to ensure types are corrects, at least by using "toString".

Comment: When I am creating the task object initially, I am giving it a key of userId with a value of " " (empty string). If the task becomes assigned to an employee, the userId is reassigned a number (i.e. 8, not "8").

Comment: @Nil you are correct. i just wanted to check if changing to `==` would show the `option` element or not.